# How can I make a desktop shortcut to start a java JAR

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a .jar file on my desktop. In order to start it I have to type a certain command in the CMD after going to my desktop using cd desktop. Currently I do this:

1. Open cmd and have C:\Users\Name
2. type cd desktop and get C:\Users\Name\Desktop
3. type the command that starts the .jar file

I am wondering is it possible to make a shortcut that would do all of this in a click without me having to do the aforementioned stuff. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save below into a `.bat` file, change if needed, and then you can use it to start the jar file.

```
::Uncomment below to hide the commands
::@echo off
cd /d "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop"
::Below is the line starts the .jar file, change it to your real one:
java -jar file.jar
```

You can also change the last line to `start "" java -jar file.jar` which won't leave the batch file window open there.

In above example, java executable folder should be in the `PATH` environment variable.
If it's not, either add it to `PATH` and reopen the batch file, or add a line:

```
cd /d "Drive:\path\to\java\executable\"
```

above the java line.

Comment: Also, it might be useful to add that the java executable folder must be in the `PATH` environment variable. It should already be the case with a regular installation, but if it is not the case, it could be something puzzling for beginners.

Comment: @Pac0  Yeah you are right, updated :)

Comment: You could replace `Name` by `%USERNAME%`. That way it always works on other sessions.

Comment: @w1ll Yeah, that's a good idea, updated, thanks :-)

Comment: The executable path can be added to the start line like this: `start "" /D "Drive:\path\to\java\executable" java -jar file.jar`.  However, for me on Windows 10, this does not close the Java command window, so you still end up with an extra unneeded window.  You can avoid that by using `javaw -jar file.jar` instead of `java -jar file.jar`.